# Rails: Error with link_to :method => post is throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Our erb view contains the following code -

```
<h1><%=@subreddit.title.capitalize%> Posts</h1>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_user_post_path(current_user)  if current_user  %>
<div id="<%= @subreddit.id  %>">
<span> Total subscribers:</span> 
<span class="subscriber_co![unt"><%=@subscriber_count%></span><br>
<%= link_to('Subscribe', subscribers_path,:remote => true, :class => 'subscribed ', :method => post)%>
</div>][1]
<br><br>
```

however this throws the following error :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni3Tb.png]

corresponding controller code -

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize
  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def show
    cids = Comment.all.map { |c| c.id}
    @vote_count_arr = cids.map { |cid| CommentVote.where(comment_id: cid).inject(0) {|sum,cv| sum+cv.vote_val}}
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.where(post_id: params[:id])
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :subreddit)
  end
end
```

I've excluded most of the controller code for the sake of brevity. please let me know how to resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `:` before `post`, so it is searching for variable or method `post` instead of symbol `:post`:

```
<%= link_to('Subscribe', subscribers_path,:remote => true, class: 'subscribed ', method: :post)%>
```